# git svn already set ... wanted to set to:

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to clone/fetch svn branch with git-svn:

```
git config --add svn-remote.stable-2012-03-29.url https://some_host/branch
git config --add svn-remote.stable-2012-03-29.fetch :refs/remotes/stable-2012-03-29
git svn fetch stable-2012-03-29
```

which gives me this error message:

```
svn-remote.stable-2012-03-29.url already set: https://some_host/branch/ wanted to set to: https://some_host/
```

I know that I probably can fix this by re-fetching all svn-repo from scratch, but it will take months or even years (due to size of repo).

So, is there any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured out how to fix it, following works:

1) I cloned trunk from scratch

```
git svn clone -T trunk/ https://some_host --revision 1104830:HEAD
```

2) Then add branches I want to fetch in `.git/config:`

```
fetch = branches/proj/proj-stable-2013-08-14:refs/remotes/proj-stable-2013-08-14
```

3) Then run

```
git svn fetch
```

wait for about 10 hours without any output from command (this was most difficult step due to absence of output), and after that git started to fetch revisions!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the *.git/config* file manually.